# mysql query does not get updated due to apostrophe sign

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oracle

```
$url = "example.com";
$data = json_decode($raw);
    $pname=$data->name;
$sql="UPDATE `client` SET pname='$pname' WHERE url='$url'";
    $query=mysql_query($sql,$link)or die(mysql_error());
```

When the json data is decoded, the value in variable $pname goes in client table. If there is an apostrophe sign (') in name then it throws an error. What changes can I make in the variable to send the name to database table?

example:
Jerry get updated with no issues
D'Cunha does not get updated as it has the apostrophe sign. The query becomes

```
"UPDATE `client` SET pname='D'Cunha' WHERE url='example.com'"
```

I found some articles but that does not say about how to find the apostrophe sign and change the variable value

Comment: `stripslashes()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()` will fix that.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*`. Use prepared statements.

Comment: This can solve if I want to run a single query. I am looping hundreds of data. How can the variable $pname value be changed with an if statement? if there is a an apostrophe sign, replace it with the format you suggested...

Comment: Inject `mysql_real_escape_string()` in the query itself then, or use prepared statements, as already stated.

Comment: how to use/inject mysql_escape_sring() stripslashes() and mysql_real_escape_string()? sorry dont know what do you mean by that. can the sign be identified with a if statement and change the value of the variable?

Comment: ...always a pleasure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `mysql_escape_string()`

```
$sql="UPDATE `client` SET pname='".mysql_escape_string($pname)."' WHERE url='$url'";
```

and learn `mysqli` or `PDO` as `mysql` is deprciated and soon going to be drop

Comment: This will certainly work but it should be noted that PHP specifically [warns against this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php): ***Warning**
This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.*

Comment: Ah, another happy ending ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use prepared statements. [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). Here's an example with mysqli:

```
$url = "example.com";
$data = json_decode($raw);
$pname=$data->name;

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $db);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE client SET pname = ? WHERE url = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $pname, $url);
$stmt->execute();
```

---

[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Thanks Mark... Im a beginner and will definitely read about prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE client SET pname = 'D\'Cunha' WHERE url = 'example.com'
```